# How can I configure a shortcut for the 'Screenshot' default program in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, shortcuts, screenshot

I remember this was a default in other distros like Xubuntu and Lubuntu. I know there's about 7 screenshot shortcuts in Settings, and I do use them, but I'd also like a "global" shortcut to launch the 'Screenshot' program with its menu so that it runs and I can choose which method to use on the fly. Is there any way to do this in an easy way? Or should I go for xbindkeys or something like that?

Comment: Are you on default Ubuntu (with gnome desktop), or on a derivative, like Xubuntu, Kubuntu, etc. That's important, because each derivative uses a different program for taking screenshots.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 20.04, Gnome Desktop. Program seems to be "GNOME Screenshots", which comes pre-installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't be able to help you with an image by image instructions, because I'm not using gnome desktop. But based on what you said, I believe you can still go through with it, since you seem to know your way around cheeking and editing the shortcuts. If someone wants to add a new reply, or edit mine, feel free.

A shortcut is doing nothing more than invoking a program, exactly how you can do with your terminal. When calling a program, you often have a lot of options, that the developers have included, that usually make our life easier.

Taking a look at the [gnome-screenshot man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gnome-screenshot), we can see a few of these options, some of them that have likely been included in the default shortcut.

I believe the option you are looking for is the `-i` one:

```
-i, --interactive
    Interactively set options in a dialog.
```

You could first try it out by opening the terminal and typing `gnome-screenshot -i` and checking if that is the behavior you are looking for. If that is the case, you can either add a new shortcut that will execute the command like that, or edit one of the existing shortcuts to add the `-i` option.

Alternatives are also trying out the screenshot program used by xfce, `xfce4-screenshooter`, or by KDE `spectacle`, which seem to open the dialog options by default. Remember that if you go with either, you will still need to edit the shortcuts to add/edit them so they run the new program of your choice. They might also pull a few dependencies when installing.

Comment: That was the command I was looking for, since gnome-screenshots only takes a screenshot. Thank you very much. Just mapped it in Settings, Shortcuts section and works like a charm. Should've looked at the man first thing, to be honest.